# Group Posts by meta_query

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to group my posts by a meta value, and can't seem to figure it out. My query below just returns "featured" posts. I would like the query to return all posts, but have the "featured" results before the rest.

Any ideas?

```
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '20',
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'tags',
            'value' => 'featured',
            'compare' => 'like'
        )
    ),
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is `rewind_posts()`. Run your query to get all the posts, run your loop and filter out all posts which is not `featured`, rewind the loop, rerun the loop and filter out `featured` posts.

Something like this will do

```
$args = [
// Your query arguments to get all postst
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tags', true ) == 'featured' ) {

            // Run your loop for featured posts

        }

    }

    $q->rewind_posts(); // Rewind the loop to rerun it

    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tags', true ) != 'featured' ) {

           // Run your loop for non featured posts

        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not quite it. The query is looking through the `tags` field for `featured`, so the use of LIKE in the $args is necessary.

Comment: Please reread your own question *...to return all posts, but have the "featured" results before the rest*. If you specifically query posts with meta value `featured`, it will only return posts with that specific meta value, then you don't need sorting. It is hard to understand then what you need reading your question and your comment above